# jQuery DataTables: Create links calling JS methods in a table cell

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm struggling with (I hope) simple problem, but somehow can't sort it out. The scenario is the following: there is a form of creating new purchase order in the admin section of the site. At the beginning there is a button of client selection: it opens a jQueryUI Dialog with a simple search form, which makes an Ajax request and shows the results using the great DataTables. Each client can have more than one shipping address, so admin should be able to click the desired shipping address link, which calls a function selectClient() setting .val() of some hidden fields in a big form and closes the Dialog.

Here is a code snippet ( only the most important fragments, also I put an alert() only in selectClient() for a better clarity ):

```
<div id="search-user">
    <form id="search-user-form">
        <label for="q">Search phrase:</label>
        <input type="text" id="q" name="q" value="" /><input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>

    <div id="search-results"></div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    function selectClient(a){
        alert(a);
    }


    $("#search-user-form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var q=$("#q").val();

        if(q.length > 0){
            $.ajax({
                url: "/service/search-users/",
                data: $("#search-user-form").serialize(),
                type: "GET",
                context: this,
                dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function(data) {

                // Service returns: {"DATA":[], "TOTALROWS":n}
                var totalRows=data.TOTALROWS;

                if(totalRows > 0){
                    $("#search-results").html('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="sResults"></table>');

                    var oTable = $('#sResults').dataTable( {
                        "bJQueryUI": true,
                        "aoColumns": [
                            { "sTitle": "Box" },
                            { "sTitle": "Name" },
                            { "sTitle": "Email" },
                            { "sTitle": "Company" },
                            { "sTitle": "Billing direction" },
                            { "sTitle": "Shipping directions" }
                        ]
                    } );


                    $.each(data.DATA, function(index, value){
                        var tmpShipping='';
                        $.each(value.shipping, function(i, v){
                                // !!! Those links give a described error:
                                tmpShipping+='<a href="#" onClick="selectClient(' + v.SHIPPINGID +')">(' + v.SHIPPINGDESCRIPTIVENAME + ') ' + v.SHIPPINGADDRESS + ', ' + v.SHIPPINGDISTRICT + ', ' + v.SHIPPINGCITY + '</a><br>';
                        })

                        $('#sResults').dataTable().fnAddData( [
                            value.BOXNUMBER,
                            value.billing.BILLINGNAME + ' ' + value.billing.BILLINGLASTNAME,
                            value.USEREMAIL,
                            value.billing.BILLINGCOMPANYNAME,
                            value.billing.BILLINGADDRESS + ', ' + value.billing.BILLINGDISTRICT + '<br>' + value.billing.BILLINGCITY + ', ' + value.billing.BILLINGREGION,
                            tmpShipping
                        ] );
                    });

                }
                else{
                    $("#search-results").html('Client not found');
                }

                oTable.fnAdjustColumnSizing();

            });
        }

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Problem: created link in the `tmpShipping` variable, when clicked, gives an error (seen in FireBird console) **selectClient is not defined**. I did a lot of search in the forums and of course Google, the only solutions i found were the ones creating a link to external resources, not JS methods. I'm using DataTables 1.9.4.

I'd greatly appreciate pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm responding my own question for the reference of whoever might encounter him-/herself in a similar situation:

The "external" function should be defined, obviously, **outside** the `$(document).ready(function(){});` block, then everything will be working as expected:

```
<script>
function selectClient(a){
   alert(a);
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#search-user-form").submit(function(e){
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when the final URL is formed, the values in variables v.SHIPPINGID, v.SHIPPINGDESCRIPTIVENAME etc., are considered to be variables.

```
!!! Those links give a described error:
                                tmpShipping+='<a href="#" onClick="selectClient(' + v.SHIPPINGID +')">(' + v.SHIPPINGDESCRIPTIVENAME + ') ' + v.SHIPPINGADDRESS + ', ' + v.SHIPPINGDISTRICT + ', ' + v.SHIPPINGCITY + '</a><br>';
```

Try to modify the line to form the URL as below.

```
!!! Those links give a described error:
                                tmpShipping+='<a href="#" onClick="selectClient(\'' + v.SHIPPINGID +'\')">(\'' + v.SHIPPINGDESCRIPTIVENAME + '\') ' + v.SHIPPINGADDRESS + ', ' + v.SHIPPINGDISTRICT + ', ' + v.SHIPPINGCITY + '</a><br>';
```

Now, the values in varibles will be passed as values wrapped in ''.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. However, it did not worked. I simplified the links created as this: `tmpShipping+='<a href="#" onClick="selectClient(1)">click</a><br>'` - still getting error "selectClient is not defined" in FireBug. But when creating links like this one: `tmpShipping+='<a href="#" onClick="alert(1)">click</a><br>'` - on click an alert gets executed. As if the DataTable cell content was rendered in a different context, without any relation to the calling page and methods defined in it...